# Copy text from file to array in class c++

Tags: c++

```
class FilesHandling{
private: fstream f;
         char *filename;
public: char *dir;
         int dir_no;
       void readFile(char *c){
          ifstream f(c);
           if (f.is_open()){
              int n; f >> n;
              dir_no = n;
              for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                dir = new char[];
                f >> dir[i];}           
            f.close();
        }
        else cout << "Can't open file" << endl;
    }
```

Hi again. i hope you can understand the code more easily now.i'm new to c++ and i need to copy data from file to an array using classes.this is a small part of a project i have to do. the problem is that when i'm calling the method from main(), it doesn't do anything;i don't get any errors but i can't see any data;

```
FilesHandling f("dir_mon.txt");
cout << f.getFN() << endl;
f.readFile("dir_mon.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < f.dir_no; i++)
    cout << f.dir[i];
```

the class had other members but i didn't copied them in here; any suggestions please ? the getFN() method is working . i can't see data copied from txt file

i searched for another method of reading the file and used std::string as you suggested but still no result.
This is how the new method looks like:

```
void getData(char *c){
    ifstream f(c);
    if (f.is_open()){while(!f.eof())

        std::getline(f, line);
        for (int i = 0; i <= line.size(); i++)
            dir[i] = line;
    }}
    f.close();
}
enter code here
```

Comment: So the question is this:  Do you want an answer that shows the C++ ways of doing this?  Your attempt is too long and has bugs (compiler and logic bugs).

Comment: if you can show me some other ways of doing this i would be really thankfull. and could you also explain me what are the logics errors ?

Comment: I'd urgently recommend using `std::string` instead of raw `char*` pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1) Wrong usage of `new[]`.

2) No check to see if the lines in the file actually matches (or exceeds) the lines specified in the `dir_no` value.

3) Unnecessary member variables, such as `fstream f`.

---

Here is a working example.  The example uses the following:

1) `std::vector<std::string> dir` instead of `char* dir`, and `std::string` instead of `char*`

2) Usage of `getline` to retrieve the lines of text from a file.

3) Note that the loop will either exit when the loop hits `dir_no` items, or if the file runs out of lines, whichever happens first.

4) Please look at how we use `std::vector` to expand the array of lines.  Note that there is no usage of `new[]` to do this, but instead, a call to the `push_back` member function of `std::vector`.

5) To output the results, usage of the algorithm function `std::copy` is used.   You don't have to learn what this does now, just letting you know what it accomplishes.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

class FilesHandling
{
    int dir_no;
    std::vector<std::string> dir;

    public: 
        void readFile(const std::string& fName)
        {
            std::ifstream f(fName.c_str());
            if (f)
            {
                f >> dir_no;
                f.ignore();
                std::string line;
                for (int i = 0; i < dir_no && getline(f, line); ++i)
                    dir.push_back(line);

                // output the results for testing
                std::copy(dir.begin(), dir.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
            }
            else 
                std::cout << "Can't open file" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
       FilesHandling fh;
       fh.readFile("abc123.txt");
    }
```

When you run this, you should see the lines of text outputted to the console.

Comment: thank you very much ! now it works. i'll try to learn from making those silly mistakes